# Sample Datasets Image Recognition; Crowdsourcing; Difficulty Score; Supervised

Tags: python

I am looking for sample datasets for image recognition.

There should be either

a) Y = picture of dog; X = n humans said "dog", "cat"... what so ever

or, even better:

b) each label has a difficulty index or confidence index Z generated by a human.
e.g. (X=picture of dog, Y=dog, Z= 0.9) (where Z=0 easy to label for humans, 1.0 very difficult to label)

Do you have any idea? I Found some examples but not really what I was looking for..

Cheers

Comment: Can you make the question title into an actual phrase that summarizes your question or problem, instead of a collection of keywords?

Comment: Question requires clarification.
Also, please provide used libraries. Or similar solutions and describe insufficient functionality.

Comment: Well, that is actually the question itself - If I would know how to formulate it properly, i guess i would have found a set via google.. I am not sure how the procedure itself is called. I am only looking for suitable datasets..